# Map object at same start value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like that

```
const object = [
    {name: 'One', data: [{x:1648741414000 , y:50},{x:1648741475000, y:60}, {x:1648741536000, y:70}]},
    {name: 'Two', data: [{x:1648741403000, y:50},{x:1648741414000 , y:60}, {x:1648741525000, y:70}]},{x:1648741476000, y:80}
    {name: 'Three', data: [{x:1648741422000, y:50},{x:1648741414000 , y:60},{x:1648741475000, y:70}, {x:1648741536000, y:90}]}
    ]
```

I need to map my array to have only x data values that match the others object

```
const result= [
     {name: 'One', data: [{x:1648741414000 , y:50},{x:1648741475000, y:60},{x:1648741536000, y:70}]},
     {name: 'Two', data: [{x:1648741414000 , y:60}, {x:1648741535000, y:70},{x:1648741476000, y:80}]},
     {name: 'Three', data: [{x:1648741414000 , y:60},{x:1648741475000, y:70}, {x:1648741536000, y:90}]}
     ]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please explain in text what you are trying to change about the input to produce the ouput.

Comment: Some people here might be picky about syntax.  Did you mean for your names to be strings? Might want to clean that up (including missing commas) to avoid drawing attention to it.

Comment: The x values in result[1] don't match the x values in the other results.

Comment: What do you mean by "x data values that match the others object" ??

Comment: The length of `object[1].data` is greater than the length of `object[0].data` and data elements have been removed entirely from the results.  Care to explain the logic?

Comment: Where does `y:90` come from in the result? Is that supposed to be `y:900` like in the corresponding input?

Comment: I want map the array to have a result with 3 object with same x values

Answer (score 0):

You could get common `x` values with their indices and slice the arrays with the found index.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'One', data: [{ x: 1648741414000, y: 50 }, { x: 1648741475000, y: 60 }, { x: 1648741536000, y: 70 }] }, { name: 'Two', data: [{ x: 1648741403000, y: 50 }, { x: 1648741414000, y: 60 }, { x: 1648741525000, y: 70 }, { x: 1648741476000, y: 80 }] }, { name: 'Three', data: [{ x: 1648741422000, y: 50 }, { x: 1648741414000, y: 60 }, { x: 1648741475000, y: 70 }, { x: 1648741536000, y: 900 }] }],
    indices = Object
        .values(array.reduce((r, { data }, _, { length }) => {
            data.some((o, i) => (r[o.x] ??= []).push(i) === length);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .find(({ length }) => length === array.length),
    result = array.map(({ name, data }, i) =>
        ({ name, data: data.slice(indices[i]) })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A bit longer code.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'One', data: [{ x: 1648741414000, y: 50 }, { x: 1648741475000, y: 60 }, { x: 1648741536000, y: 70 }] }, { name: 'Two', data: [{ x: 1648741403000, y: 50 }, { x: 1648741414000, y: 60 }, { x: 1648741525000, y: 70 }, { x: 1648741476000, y: 80 }] }, { name: 'Three', data: [{ x: 1648741422000, y: 50 }, { x: 1648741414000, y: 60 }, { x: 1648741475000, y: 70 }, { x: 1648741536000, y: 900 }] }],
    length = array.length,
    hashes = {},
    result = [];

let indices;

outer: for (const { data } of array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const { x } = data[i];
        if (!hashes[x]) hashes[x] = [];
        hashes[x].push(i);
        if (hashes[x].length === length) {
             indices = hashes[x];
             break outer;
        }
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const { name, data } = array[i];
    result.push({ name, data: data.slice(indices[i]) });
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer , what do you do ?

Comment: Can you make it more readable, instead a big on liner ?

Comment: get the `x` values and the index of the inner arrays and stop searching if the indices have a length of the wanted length. then take this array for slicing.

Comment: Can you make it less compact, and more beginner readable ?